# Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.2. Problem when creating new Mobile App (Xamarin Forms) Project

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

[image]

I have attached a screenshot of the error that I get after trying to create a new Xamarin Forms project. I have no idea how to resolve this. Please help. I want to create a cross platform application

Comment: I just tried it.  Worked for me?  I'm on VS 16.8.2.  Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1687 and Xamarin.Essentials v1.5.3.2 and .NET Standard Library 2.0.3.

Comment: @Ithra Can you try to repair Visual Studio, then try to create project again?

Comment: That worked, now it can create a project and then when I try to run the project this is the error i get : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(250,5): error XA5205: Cannot find `aapt.exe`. Please install the Android SDK Build-Tools package with the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat` program